# Is std::filesystem::directory_iterator really an iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator, filesystems, range-based-loop

Something doesn't make to sense. According to what I've read you use std::filesystem like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
  
int main()
{
    auto iterator = std::filesystem::directory_iterator("c:/somefolder");
    for (auto& i : iterator)
    {
        i.exists();
        i.file_size();
    }
}
```

I read the range-based loop as "for each i in iterator, call i.file_size()". With standard containers in C++ this is how it looks, for example a standard vector container.

std::filesystem::directory_iterator seems inconsistent. An iterator is supposed to point to elements in a container, but with std::filesystem::directory_iterator it seems to be a container itself, right? Each i in a range-based loop is a "directory_entry".

If:

```
std::vector<int> container;
for (auto& i : container)
```

Is equivalent to:

```
std::vector<int> container;
for (auto it = std::vector<int>::iterator; it != container.end(); it++)
```

What's:

```
for (auto i : iterator)
```

Equivalent to?

What is happening in the range-based loop above? Is it wrong to read that loop as "for each i in iterator"? The i value is a std::filesystem::directory_entry, but what is being iterated over in the loop? What container?

Comment: A `directory_iterator` **is** a valid iterator, and you can use it in the normal ways (increment, compare, dereference). It can **also** be used in the way you show, as a range.

Comment: @BobTFish In this example what is being iterator over? How would this be written without a range-based for loop, so I can understand.

Comment: Seem stuck on the need for a container, and not what the iterator design pattern is intended to do. Like provide a common interface for iterating. Your channel up/down buttons are iterators. Your first code block is also nonsensical. `exists()` returns a bool, but you don't care about it or make any checks against it. You also do nothing with the file size. And as the answers point out, you seem to misunderstand just what is required for a range-based for loop as well.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator) it's a [LegacyInputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator). So yes it's a "true" iterator.

There are overloaded [`begin` and `end`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/begin) functions. The `begin` function returns the iterator unmodified, and the `end` function doesn't use the argument and instead returns a default-constructed iterator. They exists just to support the range-for loop.

So if you have:

```
auto iterator = std::filesystem::directory_iterator("c:/somefolder");
```

then

```
iterator == begin(iterator) && std::filesystem::directory_iterator() == end(iterator)
```

will be true.

---

Note that since `begin` will return the iterator unmodified, even after you do `iterator++` the condition `iterator == begin(iterator)` will be true.

---

To iterate over a directory "manually" you just do it *almost* like any other iterator:

```
for (auto iterator = std::filesystem::directory_iterator("c:/somefolder");
     iterator != std::filesystem::directory_iterator();
     iterator++)
{
    // Use the iterator
    std::cout << "The path is " << iterator->path() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: The iterator is iterating over std::filesystem::directory_entry, so how would I iterate over this manually? directory_entry doesn't have begin() and end().

Comment: @Zebrafish `directory_iterator` is a proper iterator, much like any other iterator. Dereferencing it returns a `directory_entry` structure, just like any other iterator returns some other type on dereferencing (like `std::vector<int>::iterator` returns an `int`).

Comment: Yes, it's just that usually an iterator isn't the second part of a range-based loop after the ":", is it?

Comment: @Zebrafish That's because the overloaded `std::begin` and `std::end` functions. The right-hand-side of the `:` in a range-for doesn't need to have `begin` and `end` member functions, only overloaded `begin` and `end` functions in the right scope. And as mentioned in my answer, the overloads for `directory_iterator` are made with range-for iteration in mind, and are implemented in a way to allow the iterator to be used as such.

Answer (score 1):

The range-based for loop uses [overloads of `std::begin` and `std::end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/directory_iterator/begin):

```
directory_iterator begin( directory_iterator iter ) noexcept;
directory_iterator end( const directory_iterator& ) noexcept;
```

Note how calling `begin` on a `directory_iterator` returns the `directory_iterator` itself, while `end` ignores its argument and "Returns a default-constructed directory_iterator, which serves as the end iterator."

Answer (score 1):

A ranged-based for loop doesn't always need a container to work. It can also loop over a range which is what it's doing in this case.

A ranged-based for loop is structured as follows:

```
auto && __range = range_expression ;
for ( ; begin_expr != end_expr ; ++begin_expr) {

    range_declaration = *__begin;
    loop_statement

}
```

Where `begin_expr` and `end_expr` [are](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) :

> Otherwise, `begin_expr` is `begin(__range)` and `end_expr` is `end(__range)`, which are found via argument-dependent lookup (non-ADL
> lookup is not performed).

Since `directory_iterator` overloads `begin` and `end` it functions just like a normal `LegacyInputIterator`.

```
for (auto i : iterator)
```

We're not actually "looping over the iterator" as you'd do with a container because the iterator itself is no container as you noted, we're accessing the iterator and incrementing it on repeat until we reach `end()`. The container here is `directory_entry`.

Comment: If it's iterating over directory_entry why doesn't directory_entry have begin() and end() to compare with? How would this be written without the range-based loop, so I can understand?

Comment: @Zebrafish `directory_entry` doesn't expose another way (at the moment of writing) to iterate over its files. `operator*` on this iterator does something OS specific.

Comment: It *doesn't* overload `begin` and `end`: they are in the `std::filesystem` namespace, and that seems to make it a bit of a hassle to get ADL right.